# Capture the value of multiple cell range in a custom formulaarray

Tags: vba, excel

I've written my own function in VBA to do some things.
Parameters are Variant.

```
Private Function ProcessedValuesEx(pValues As Variant)
```

The problem occurs when I select a multiple cell range as my function parameter.

When it executes, the parameter has no value. I'm not able to see any content. Even with the VBA inspector.

When selection only one cell there is no problem. The parameter gets the content of the cell.

Comment: are you able to show more of the function - I'd like to see what you do with pValues

Comment: If you want to only deal with a single cell then you can use the top-left cell of any passed (single-area) range using `pValues(1)`.

Comment: What is being passed in as an argument? A range object? The Locals window will show a Variant(Range) fine. Can you show some code from where the function is called? Can you also stick in the first line of the function "Debug.Print TypeName(pValues)" and tell us what it says when you run?

Comment: As an example: `Sub b()
    Debug.Print f(Selection)
End Sub
Function f(aVariant)
    f = TypeName(aVariant)
End Function` always prints "Range" regardless of the number of cells selected.

Comment: I just wanted to acces it's elements if it's an array (multiple cells).
when it's only a cell, it's easy. But when it's a multiple cell, how can I determine if it's a multiple cell range?

Tim and Cor_Blimey, I've seen in locals appear the array in the local variable and its accessible. Thank you.
But how can I know the values belong to selection or i'm accessing the cell next to my selection?
For example: pvalues(1) returns the content of one cell, pValues(2) returns the content of the next cell, istead it's being selected in the range or not.

Comment: Hi!!

I've found my error.

I was referencing pValues as Range(pValues).Address instead of pValues.Address and was giving me an error.

Thank you for your comments, helped me to find my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set the argument as a range, and then loop through each cell in the range, like so:

```
Private Function ProcessedValuesEx(ByVal rValues As Range)

    Dim pValue As Range

    For Each pValue In rValues.Cells
        'Do something with pValue here
    Next pValue

End Function
```